# Help with a mathematical induction problem

Tags: induction

hi I started learning mathematical induction and I have a problem with a specific one

I need to prove that the left side is equal to the right side and I got lost on the way, so any answers will really help

$$ 1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+....(2n)^2=\frac{n}{3}(2n+1)(4n+1)$$
edit:
this is my progress so far: $n=1$:

$$ 1^2 +2^2 =5=\frac{1}{3}\times3\times5$$

assumption $n=k$:
$$ 1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+....(2k)^2=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1)$$
$n=k+1$
$$ 1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+....(2k+1)^2=\frac{k+1}{3}(2k+3)(4k+5)$$

what I tried to do is opening the left side to look like the right side

$$ \frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1)+ (2k+1)^2 (2k+2)^2 =\frac{k}{3}8k^2+6k+1+8k^2+12k+5$$

and right from here is when I get lost, tried multiplying all the equation with 3
but really didnt get close

so thats what I tried to do any tips will help, and maybe you could try to tell me how should I try to look at both sides for future induction

Comment: Start with proving the equality for $n=1$ and post it on your answer! You have to show us some effort to solve the question yourself :)

Comment: Please show us your original steps - we may then be able to show you where you went wrong

Comment: ok, thanks couple of moments I will edit

Comment: @shahar Hint: Try to start by verifying the situation when $n$ is a small number, and then assume that the assumption $P_n$ is true and try to show that if $P_n$ is true then $P_{n+1}$ is also true.

Comment: In the inductive step you basically want to show that $\frac n3 (2n+1)(4n+1) + (2n+1)^2 + (2n+2)^2 = \frac {n+1}3 (2(n+1)+1)(4(n+1)+1)$

Comment: ok so I edited it for the steps I did, and to where I got confused

Comment: For $n=k+1$ you have a typo.... Inside the parenthesis....

Comment: @shahar Sometimes proving a more general case can be somewhat easier than a more specific one. With your question, such as shown in [Sum of Consecutive Squares](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56982.html), you can try using induction to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{m} i^2 = \frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{6}$. Then you can replace $m$ with $2n$ to get the specific result you're trying to prove. By doing this, you may find the algebra somewhat easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+\cdots+ [2(k+1)]^2&=1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+\cdots(2k)^2+(2k+1)^2+(2k+2)^2 \\&=1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+\cdots(2k)^2+4k^2+4k+1+4k^2+8k+4\\&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +8k^2+12k+5\end{align}

On the other hand,

$\begin{align}
\frac{k+1}{3}(2k+3)(4k+5) &=
\frac{k}{3}(2k+3)(4k+5) +\frac{1}{3}(2k+3)(4k+5) \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+5) +\frac{k}{3}(2)(4k+5)+\frac{1}{3}(2k+3)(4k+5) \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4)+ \frac{k}{3}(2)(4k+5) + \frac{1}{3}(2k+3)(4k+5) \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[k(2k+1)(4)+ k(2)(4k+5) +(2k+3)(4k+5)] \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[4k(2k+1)+ 4k(2k+1)+6k +(2k+3)(4k+5)] \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[8k(2k+1)+6k +(2k+1)(4k+5)+2(4k+5)] \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[(12k+5)(2k+1)+6k+8k+10]\\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[(12k+5)(2k+1)+14k+10] \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[5(2k+1)^2+4k^2+16k+10] \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +\frac{1}{3}[24k^2+36k+15] \\
&=\frac{k}{3}(2k+1)(4k+1) +8k^2+12k+5 \\
&=1^2 +  2^2 + 3^2  + 4^2+\cdots+ [2(k+1)]^2
\end{align}$

And we're done

Comment: thanks for your effort, that really helped me